# Increase point radius when tootip shown for certain data on Charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/). I want make the point hidden by default, but when a tooltip shown for certain data, highlight the data by increase the radius of its point.

Following codes is what I had tried. But it only increase the radius of point if mouse hover on it. I want the radius increased as long as the tooltip is shown.

Thanks for any helps.

```js
var myChart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "l1",
        borderColor: `hsla(150, 60%, 33%, 1)`,
        backgroundColor: `hsla(150, 60%, 33%, 0.8)`,
        fill: false,
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 3 }],
      },{
        label: "l2",
        borderColor: `hsla(210, 60%, 33%, 1)`,
        backgroundColor: `hsla(210, 60%, 33%, 0.8)`,
        fill: false,
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 1 }],
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 1,
        hoverRadius: 4,
      },
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
      position: 'nearest',
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the `mode` and `intersect` options for `hover` with the same value used for `tooltips`.

```
...
hover: {
  mode: 'index',
  intersect: false
}
...
```

This way the `hover` event will be triggered the same way the `tooltips` is triggered.

```js
var myChart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "l1",
        borderColor: `hsla(150, 60%, 33%, 1)`,
        backgroundColor: `hsla(150, 60%, 33%, 0.8)`,
        fill: false,
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 3 }],
      },{
        label: "l2",
        borderColor: `hsla(210, 60%, 33%, 1)`,
        backgroundColor: `hsla(210, 60%, 33%, 0.8)`,
        fill: false,
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 1 }],
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 1,
        hoverRadius: 4,
      },
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
      position: 'nearest',
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false          
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" />
```

Comment: Wow, it works great. I hadn't found out the `hover` attribute in `options` for a long time.